# Unable to ad adverts to an android app using admob

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

I am trying to ad some ads to my android application using admob, but when the app loads, the adview gives an error saying

> You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges

I do have that in the manifest though, i cant show you as i am not to post images.

So i don't know why it's doing this?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an activity in android manifest fail to integrate admod to your map. Entry should be

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"               android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Here is good tutorial on how to integrate addmob with your app.

[Android admob tutorial](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

Comment: I have already done that though:  `<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />`

Comment: Then I would suggest uninstall app and do a clean build and deploy. From the error message, it is clear that android couldn't properly read AdActivity.

Comment: @LiamW it is a bit confusing when you say *this didn't work* while you have accepted the answer. Did you feel pressured to mark it or did you forget to clean-up your comments?